# On ScrollDown, I want to animate my nav bar to go left and hide, On ScrollUp I want my nav bar to go right and appear

Tags: javascript, scroll, jquery-animate, navbar

This is the code I have and currently it slides the nav bar left and right, continuously, while I scroll, I need it to slide in leftwards only once as I am scrolling down. Then when I scroll up I want it to slide out to the right and re-appear:

```
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scrollTop > lastScrollTop && scrollTop > pixelsFromTheTop){ // ensure that the header doesnt disappear too early
            // downscroll
            $header.one("scrollDown", function () { $('navbar').animate({width: "toggle",},250)})(settings.transitionTime);

        } else {
            // upscroll
            $header.animate({width: "toggle",},250);(settings.transitionTime);
        }
        lastScrollTop = scrollTop;
    }
};
```

I used this plugin to help me get started: [HidingNavBarPlugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/menu/jQuery-Plugin-For-Auto-Hiding-Navigation-Menu-showup.html) Can anyone help me figure this out? :)

Comment: Put your working code in jsfiddle and post the link.

Comment: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/8h72820t/1/) Heres the link to it but I cant seem to get it to work in jsfiddle @RaviH

Comment: I am trying to make it so it doesn't continue repeating the animation as I scroll down. Then when I scroll up I want the animation to happen again, but only once.

Scroll down: animate (slide left) navbar (hide)
Scroll up: animate (slide right) navbar (show)

@RaviH